# Using nginx to proxy static files from node js (express)

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, static

I have a basic nginx setup, where requests to example.com/xyz1 are proxied to 127.0.0.1:9000 and requests to example.com/xyz2 are proxied to 127.0.0.1:9001.

On 127.0.0.1:9000 runs an express server, that should only server static files.
For my index.html there is no problem. But all dependencies like css and JS files can not be resolved.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + 'public'));

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/xyz1", (err, database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    db = database;

    console.log('Connected to mongoDb');
    app.listen(9000, () => {
            console.log('Express-Server listening on port 9000');
    })
})

app.get('/xyz1', (req, res) => {
    console.log('xyz1');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/' + 'index.html');
    //res.send('Hello World xyz1');
})
```

My folder structure for xyz1:

- xyz1

  - server.js
  - ...
  - public

    - index.html
    - style

      - css files
    - scripts

      - JS files

if some needs to see the nginx configuration, please tell me.

Comment: I've been asking around and it's as if no one knows. Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not the way I wanted it to be. But I got it working. So when you have http://example.com/xyz1/ proxied to your app, the static folder is at http://example.com/xyz1/<static_files>. You have to make sure that your static files are linked correctly in the html pages. But, from I read, is that you should serve static files directly with nginx. It's much faster.